# Use MetroFramework control item in C#

Tags: c#

When I dropdown the MetroButton from Toolbox, but control item does not

display in the Metroforms, as follow picture

[image]

How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think it is a bug, waiting for fix.